# handle null values while converting string to date in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I am building a job in AWS Glue and my table has a column named as booking with string data type. It includes some null values along with date information.
While converting string to date using **pySpark **data frame, these null values are causing issue.

| booking | name |
| --- | --- |
| 11.01.2022 | John |
| null | max |

I tried multiple work around.

1. use **fillna() & fill()** to replace null value with dummy date as 01.01.1900. Unfortunately glue job throws an error stating that *ImportError: cannot import name 'fill' from 'pyspark.sql.functions'*
   My idea was to replace null values with dummy date and then convert it using to_date function.
2. writing when condition:

df_spark = df_spark.withColumn(
"booking",
when(df_spark.booking.isNull(), "01.01.1900")
.otherwise(df_spark.booking)
)

df_spark = df_spark.withColumn(
"buchungs_datum",
to_date(df_spark["buchungs_datum"],"dd.MM.yyyy")
)

This also throws super weird error message (attached with the screenshot)

[image]

3. Below statement also does not work.

df_spark = df_spark.withColumn(
"booking", to_date(df_spark["booking"], None)
)

Could you please help me with the correct method here?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce function in ‘WithColumn’. This will replace null to value you provide.

Comment: actually first statement in 2nd step does write my desired value. The problem is it is not getting converted to date datatype. and throws error message like shown in my screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately glue job throws an error stating that ImportError:
> cannot import name 'fill' from 'pyspark.sql.functions'

The `fill` is a method that you call on a specific `DataFrame` so you don't have import it. It is part of PySpark natively, so if rest of PySpark code runs fine, then there shouldn't a problem with it. You can refer to docs on how to use it here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill.html#pyspark-sql-dataframenafunctions-fill